# Random is returning the same output every time

Tags: c++, random, vector

I wrote this code which is working fine but everytime the output is the same. So nothing random about it. Curious to know why! 
Assumptions: 33 students 
First row : 7 students
2nd row   : 9 students
3rd row   : 9 students
4th row   : 8 students

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   vector<int> random;

   for (int i = 1; i < 34; i++)
      random.push_back(i);

   random_shuffle(random.begin(), random.end());

   for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
      cout << random[i] << " " ;
   cout << endl;

   int i = 7;
   int num_seats = 1;

   for (int j = 1; j <=3; j++) {
      while (num_seats < 10 && i < 33) {
         cout << random[i++] << " " ;
         num_seats++;
      }
      cout << endl;
      num_seats = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, C++11 has an [`iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) function that can save you from filling your vector with consecutive numbers.

Comment: Did you provide a [random seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) to the random number generator you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialise the random number generator first. Random number generation depends on a "seed value". To have a unique seed value every time your program is executed, you can rely on the current time. `time(NULL)` returns the number of seconds which represents the current time -- which can be that unique seed.

Try adding this in the first line inside `main()`

```
srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
```

Comment: Correct, but a little explanation of why his "problem" exists in the first place might be helpful

Comment: @Itjax: At the risk of sounding like a clairvoyant, I'd wager that's the point of this particular section of the curriculum (that is, to teach how PRNG works).

Comment: It's not actually specified that `random_shuffle` uses `rand()` as a source of randomness, so this isn't necessarily portable.

Answer (score 2):

The `random_shuffle()` overload you use accesses an unspecified source of randomness. It's almost certainly using `rand()`, which would mean you'd need to use `srand()` to seed it to get varying random shuffles.

However a more portable solution would be to specify a source of randomness so you don't have to just assume `rand()` is used. If your implementation is C++11 then the best option is to use `shuffle()` and an engine from the `<random>` library:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(34);
    iota(begin(v), end(v), 1);

    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
    std::mt19937_64 eng(seed);

    shuffle(begin(v), end(v), eng);

    copy(begin(v), end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Absent C++11 you can use the `random_shuffle()` overload that takes a random number generator, so that the program portably specifies the source of randomness:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

struct RNG {
    int operator() (int n) {
        return static_cast<int>(std::rand()/(static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX)+1) * n);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(34);
    for (int i=0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        v[i] = i + 1;

    std::srand(std::time(NULL));
    random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), RNG());

    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: +1, but if you are using `C++11`, why don't you use `{}` to avoid most-vexing parse instead of the extra `()`. It also keeps the difference between `random_device` construction and calling more clear.

Comment: @KillianDS I considered it, however I decided to make my example support some popular compilers that haven't yet implemented generalized initialization syntax but which do have the necessary C++11 library components.